# dc.js chart becomes smaller when insert it in div with bootstrap class 'collapsibe'

Tags: bootstrap-4, dc.js

I have a div with dc.js charts. I wanted to make this div collapsible and i added the bootstrap 4 collapse class. When i add the collapse class in the div the charts get smaller (not as wide as before). Everything else works fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, I tried to reproduce but I couldn't get it to work. Here is the fiddle I started, maybe you can fork it and get it working to demonstrate the problem? https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/z6ywx97k/9/ This is probably a CSS issue and not really to do with dc.js, but I'm glad to help anyway.